# Role of "meta's super class's __init__", during metaclass coding?

Tags: python

This sounds like a simple question, however I could not find a straightforward answer in websites.

Example code: (most of the time, people will write a metaclass this way.)

```
class MyMeta(type):

    def __new__(meta, name, bases, dct):    
        return super(MyMeta, meta).__new__(meta, name, bases, dct)

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        print "Initializing class", name
        super(MyMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)
```

My questions:

(1) What exactly is `super(MyMeta, cls)` referring to in the section of `__init__`?    Given `MyMeta` is an obj from `type`, then this `super(MyMeta, cls)` should refer to type's `__init__`,  am I correct?

(2) It is easy to understand `super(MyMeta, meta).__new__.....`.  This should invoke `type.__new__` and start creating a targeted class.  This statement is a must. Without it, it could not finish creating the class. However, what is the role of `super(MyMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)`? Technically speaking (a lot of web example), you could just delete this statement, without hitting any error.     Very confusing.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [implementation of type.__init__](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0360a9d015ddbc4e3d58e3ab4b433da27bf1db3a/Objects/typeobject.c#L2263) it seems to do nothing terribly interesting -- it error checks the number of arguments and then calls `object.__init__`.

The implementation of [`object.__init__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0360a9d015ddbc4e3d58e3ab4b433da27bf1db3a/Objects/typeobject.c#L3528) also isn't terribly interesting.  Again just type checking for the number of arguments.

So while calling `type.__init__(...)` (via `super()`) really doesn't do much of anything, it's just a best practice to call a superclass's method if you're overriding and why you'll commonly see it (even in a metaclass where it does literally nothing).  The interesting cases with `super()` happen when you multiple inherit (which I guess is technically possible with metaclasses but personally I'd strongly discourage that -- you've already got enough magic in play given you're implementing a metaclass).

Comment: Thanks for explanation. It helps indeed.